# Ng-click - does the order matter when calling multiple methods?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-click

When calling multiple methods with `ng-click`, as in

```
ng-click="select(); highlight()"
```

do they get executed in order, i.e. first `select()` and then `highlight()`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Yes* they are executed in the manner they are written/called.

See the [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Sourabh_/HB7LU/13494/).

This is from the fiddle:

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <button ng-click="test(); test1(); test3(); test4();">TEst</button>
</div>
```

Js:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

//myApp.directive('myDirective', function() {});
//myApp.factory('myService', function() {});



function MyCtrl($scope) {
      $scope.test = function(){
       console.log("Hello1");
      }
      $scope.test1 = function(){
       console.log("Hello2");
      }
      $scope.test3 = function(){
       console.log("Hello3");
      }
      $scope.test4 = function(){
       console.log("Hello4");
      }
    }
```